# Где должна происходить работа с базой данных?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Где считается **правильным** работать с базой данных? В контроллере или в отдельном файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тут 2 момента.

первый: в .NET Core работа с БД строится по таким же принципам, что и в классическом .NET (далее привожу примеры из классического .NET, т.к. примеров по .NET Core в инете меньше и что то может не заработать)

второй момент философский: а нужен ли отдельный слой для работы с БД?

если вы пишете простое приложение, то тупо пишете весь код в контроллер. плюсом будет то, что быстро напишете и все будет отлично работать.

https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/3.5.php

если у вас в перспективе будет много контроллеров, много моделей и вьюх, то чтобы не запутаться потом, нужно аккуратно все раскладывать по типизированным моделям и использовать для этого надстройку над ADO.NET. Можете выбрать любую на свой вкус. Например, Dapper (используется разработчкими stackoverflow).

https://blog.byndyu.ru/2013/03/dapper-queryobject-orm.html